# What is wrong with my assembly language code

Tags: assembly, output, x86-16

I have a problem with this code, it is meant to collect a number and double it, but it only accept numbers between 1 and 9,  and output the second value for all double of numbers between 5 and 9, what can be done to allow it output the right value

```
;DOUBLE THIS PROGRAM PROMPTS THE USER TO ENTER A NUMBER
;DOUBLE THE NUMBER,AMD OUTPUT THE RESULT
.model small
.stack
.data
prompt db 0ah,0dh,  'enter the number : $'
msg db 0ah,0dh,  'Double your number is : '
result db 0ah,0dh, '$'
.code
start:
      mov ax,@data
      mov ds,ax


      lea dx,prompt             
      mov ah, 9               ;dos fn to output string up to $
      int 21h
      mov ah,1                ;dos fn to input byte into al
      int 21h
      sub al,30h                ;convert from ascii to integer
      add al,al                 ;sum inputted value to itself
      aaa
      or al,30h

      mov result,al             ;add the double value of the value to result



      lea dx, msg 

      mov ah, 9
      int 21h


      mov ah,4ch
      int 21h            

      end start
```

Comment: You are confusing decimal digits and numbers.

Comment: How can I correct it pls

Comment: You're using `aaa` wrong: it's designed for use after adding two BCD digits packed into a single byte.  It's not even available in 64bit mode.  It's usually best to convert **strings** to binary integers (like the C `atoi` function does), do math, then convert back to a string.  In this case, you could loop over the string doing add-with-carry on the decimal digits.  But you'd have to detect and handle base10 carry, not CF and `adc`.

Comment: Pls can I get an example, not into assembly language

Comment: To complete your homework you need to take the doubled value and turn it into an ascii string.  Clearly, 0-4 will work if you get rid of the `aaa` instruction.  Not sure why you have that in there.  `5-9`, when doubled, will be greater than 9...  So you need to figure out how to take a number and convert it into two ascii representations of the two digits.  Have you looked through your class notes, course book and other materials?  Seems unlikely that the professor has left you high and dry without the info you need to complete this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got a few problems in your program:

- You didn't reserve the necessary space to store the *byte sized* result. You need an extra zero after the `db` directive.

  ```
  result db 0, 0ah, 0dh, '$'
  ```
- Because doubling the numbers from 5 to 9 will inevitably yield a 2-digit result, you simply have to change the result to *word size*.

  ```
  result db 0, 0, 0ah, 0dh, '$'
  ```
- You are using the `aaa` instruction wrong. Luckily there is the `aam` instruction that suits your purpose.

  > AAM divides AL by ten and stores the quotient in AH, leaving the remainder in AL.

  The next code will always display the result with 2 digits. If desired, you could replace the character "0" in AL with a " " just before writing AX in the result variable.

  ```
  aam
  or   ax, 3030h
  xchg al, ah
  mov  result, ax
  ```